# How can I test this function which erases off the list all elements, whose data is "equal" to the reference data

Tags: c

I have this function and I want to test it and see if it does the job but it doesn't return
and when I try to change its return type to (t_list*) and make it return (node)
the compiler gives me segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct  s_list
{
    struct s_list *next;
    void    *data;
}  t_list;


void    ft_list_remove_if(t_list **begin_list, void *data_ref, int (*cmp)())
{
    t_list *root;
    t_list *node;
    t_list *next;

    root = *begin_list;
    node = *begin_list;
    while (root)
    {
        next = (*root).next;
        if ((cmp)(root->data, data_ref) == 0)
        {
            if (root == *begin_list)
            {
                *begin_list = next;
            }
            node->next = next;
            free(root);
        }
        node = root;
        root = next;
    }
}
```

in the main I created the "data_ref" and I made 5 structures some of them has "data_ref" and I linked them together
but when I call the function it gives me 
segmentation fault

```
t_list *res;
res = ft_list_remove_if(ptr, str, strcmp);
```

ptr has the adress of the head of the list and str has the data_ref

Comment: The compiler gives you a segmentation fault? What's the changed code that you tried? Could you post that instead?

Comment: Can you show the code with the problem? Your compiler should not crash. Your program *could*.

Comment: You are going to have to build a working example to show us the described behavior.